# python: recursive check to determine whether string is a palindrome

Tags: python, string, recursion

My task is to define a procedure is_palindrome, that takes as input a string, and returns a boolean indicating if the input string is a palindrome. In this case a single letter should return True, as should an empty string `''`.

Unfortunately, I'm not getting the expected results. I appreciate the help.

My code version 1:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    if s == '':
        return True
    else:
        if (ord(s[0]) - ord(s[len(s)-1])) == 0:
            is_palindrome(s[1:len(s)-1])
        else:
            return False

print is_palindrome('')
#>>> True    (expected = True)

print is_palindrome('abab')
#>>> False    (expected = False)

print is_palindrome('abba')
#>>> None    (expected = True)

print is_palindrome('andrea')
#>>> None    (expected = False)

print is_palindrome('abaaba')
#>>> None    (expected = True)
```

I followed my code through the debugger and it seems the logic is correct as the code takes the appropriate path. However, the end result seems to switch to 'None' for some of the cases as highlighted above.

If I change my code to the following:

My code version 2:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
        if s == '':
            result = True
        else:
            if (ord(s[0]) - ord(s[len(s)-1])) == 0:
                is_palindrome(s[1:len(s)-1])
            else:
                result = False
        return result

print is_palindrome('')
#>>> True    (expected = True)

print is_palindrome('abab')
#>>> False    (expected = False)

print is_palindrome('abba')
#>>> Error    (expected = True)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment 

print is_palindrome('andrea')
#>>> Error   (expected = False)         
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment

print is_palindrome('abaaba')
#>>> Error    (expected = True)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: try `result = is_palindrome(s[1:len(s)-1])` in the if clause

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: This is very odd: `(ord(s[0]) - ord(s[len(s)-1])) == 0`.  Wouldn't `s[0] == s[-1]` work?

Comment: @NedBatchelder - nope not homework. I'm way past that in my life. I'm just messing around with a free online course to learn. :)

Comment: likewise wouldnt `s == "".join(reversed(s))` work to identify a palindrome?

Comment: @NedBatchelder - you are right. s[0] == s[-1] is much cleaner.

Comment: also as far as I can tell you dont account for the single letter case

Comment: @JoranBeasley: well, if we're doing that, why not `s == s[::-1]`?  Presumably the OP has a recursion requirement.  [PS: the single-letter case works, because `s[0] == s[len(s)-1] == s[1-1] == s[0]`.]

Comment: @JoranBeasley - your suggestion to use ''.join(reversed(s)) does the trick too and is a much better solution. But I should have been more clear in my task as I wanted to stay away from pre-built python methods/functions.

Comment: @JoranBeasley = the original code with the fix suggested by mVChr will account for a single letter situation. All that was missing was the 'return' statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first example, you forgot a return statement:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    if s == '':
        return True
    else:
        if (ord(s[0]) - ord(s[len(s)-1])) == 0:
            # v-- forgot this here
            return is_palindrome(s[1:len(s)-1])
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out my oversight. Duh! Thank you very much. I have also made the changes as suggested by Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Also note the shorthand used by many of the answerers. `s[1:len(s)-1]` is more concisely written as `s[1:-1]`. I think this mainly matters for concise code, but if you prefer to use `len()`, better to call it only once at the beginning of the function and reuse the result. I'm sure mVChr knows all of this, but since the OP is new to Python, I thought it was worth making the extra note.

Comment: @EMS - agree to your point and thank you for bringing that to my attention. I am new to python. :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
        is_palindrome(s[1:len(s)-1])
```

needs to be...

```
        return is_palindrome(s[1:len(s)-1])
```

in your first version, or

```
        result = is_palindrome(s[1:len(s)-1])
```

in your second. Otherwise, you never actually propagate the recursive call's return value back to the original caller.

Answer (score 3):

```
# ask user to enter any string
a = raw_input("Enter the string : ")
#palindrome check
print (a == a[::-1]) and "String is palindrome" or "String is not palindrome"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    if not s:
        return True
    else:
        return s[0]==s[-1] and is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
```

or, if you want a one-liner:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    return (not s) or (s[0]==s[-1] and is_palindrome(s[1:-1]))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Can anyone explain the intuition for why Python indexing should work correctly in the one-liner when the input is a single character? I've tested it out and it does work, but the idea that `'a'[1:-1]` returns the empty string is bizarre. If `'a'[1]` gives an error, then shouldn't `'a'[1:-1]` also give an error? It just seems unPythonic to me. It appears that `list[K:-1]` gives back `''` for any `K > len(list)`. Strange; I think I'd prefer an index error.

Comment: @EMS: it's because though index 1 does not exist, `'a'[1:]` /is/ empty, as expected. With `L=[1,2,3,4]`, `L[7:]` is `[]`, which is intuitive. Does that explain things a little?

Comment: But by the same logic, `L[7]` (or `L[7:8]` if you prefer) is just the empty list too (any subset of the empty list is the empty list), so no, this does not seem intuitive at all (since `L[7]` would give an error). Why is `L[7:8]` the empty list, but `L[7]` is an error?

Comment: I guess I am coming at this from more of a C-style perspective. I expect for something like a list that `L[i]` points to a spot in memory and gets the element of `L` living there. `L[i:j]` is just shorthand for the run of memory spots holding `L[i]` ... up to `L[j-1]`. If it tries to get `L[i]` and there is no such memory spot associated with `L`, then it should stop right there. The empty character is still a character after all.

Comment: If I didn't assign anything to spot `i` of `L`, then it seems not so good for Python to make something up just because I asked for a run of objects instead of just one single object. Python has some nice syntactical conventions, but for a data structure like a list this seems contradictory. If `L[i]` isn't a thing, then surely `L[i:-1]` isn't a thing either, and if one gives an error so should the other. My two cents of course. Smarter minds than me made Python, so I am sure they had their reasons.

Comment: `L[7]` says get me the thing at index 7, which does not exist. However, `L[x:y]` for arbitrary x and y means get be the things between index x and index y. Since there is nothing between those indices, the empty list is returned. In your case, it is a coincidence that y=x+1. Still, `L[x:x+1]` does not evaluate to `L[x]`, as I suspect you expect

Comment: Yes. You are looking at this from the C perspective, in which case, your expectation of "this should segFault" is correct. But [one of Guido's principles in developing python was that "everything should evaluate to something"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugqu10JV7dk&feature=my_watch_later_videos&list=WLEA0FC56DA20AF962) and the most intuitive something here is `[]`. That's why you get this behavior

Comment: But then why does `L[7]` fail to evaluate to something? If `L[7:8]` is the empty list, then why isn't `L[7]` equal to `None` or something? It just seems inconsistent. I get what you're saying. `L[x:x+1]` says, "first, whatever I may find, my return object is some list" and *then* goes looking for elements to put in it. It finds none, so the list is a list with no elements. That's fine, I get it. But why then doesn't `L[7]` say "whatever I may return, it must be some single object" and then, finding no object to put there, returns `None`?

Comment: As a side note, for numerical programming this empty list convention is not the desired behavior. Failing to throw errors when indexing out of range for an object is a bad thing. I'm actually *very* surprised that NumPy's creators did not change this for their ndarrays.

Comment: That's a really good question. I had to think for a minute. If `L[7]` was `None`, then the programmer thinks "ah! there's something there, which means I can assign to it" <- wrong. Because in order to do, python would have to "fill the gap" with `None`s, wasting memory. Also, this would be no different from a `[None]*8`, which would lead to annoying software design errors

Comment: That is a good point, you could mistake something being there. At least the empty set convention for lists is unmistakable in the sense that you know the list does not contain any elements at those spots. I suppose `L[7]` could also return `[]`, but then the type may be different than what the programmer expected.

Comment: `L[7]` returning `[]` would mean that at the 7th index of L, there exists an empty list. You are still thinking of this in C terms. Python lists need not be homogenous, so this would be an issue as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13918/discussion-between-inspectorg4dget-and-ems)

Answer (score 2):

Let's step through your second example, line by line.:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
```

In this case let's let s = "abba", which is the first string you got an error on:

```
        if s == '':
```

is evaluated as

```
        if 'abba' == '':
```

Which is `False`, so we skip ahead to `else`:

```
        else:
            if (ord(s[0]) - ord(s[len(s)-1])) == 0:
```

This `if` statement is equivalent to:

```
            if (97 - 97) == 0:
```

It's `True`, so recursion happens:

```
                is_palindrome(s[1:len(s)-1])
```

or

```
                is_palindrome('bb')
```

Now whatever is the result of this recursion, we ignore it, because the return value is not saved. Thus, when we get to this line:

```
        return result
```

We never defined what `result` was, so Python flips out.

Other posters already did an excellent job of answering your question. I'm posting to demonstrate the importance of tracing a program to find/fix bugs.

Comment: Joel thank you very much for that demonstration of tracing my function. I will incorporate that into my practice as I write and learn.

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta en Java

```
public class Varios {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( pali("anitalavalatina"));
  }
  static boolean pali(String palabra){
    System.out.println(palabra);
    if (palabra.length()-1<2) 
            return true;
    if(palabra.charAt(0)!=palabra.charAt(palabra.length()-1)) return false;
    return pali(palabra.substring(1,palabra.length()-1));
  }

}
```